# Event-style key input with python ncurses

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I'm trying to create a python script that will do a load of computation while continually updating a curses interface (for the purposes of this question, just imagine it's a progress bar). The code is structured like this:

```
while notDone:
     compute()
     updateScreen()
```

I'd like to allow the user to hit a button to quit the program, but the only way I know how with curses is like this:

```
while notDone:
     compute()
     updateScreen()
     c = screen.getch()
     if c == "q": break
```

Which won't work, because it means that after each iteration, the script will *wait* for the user to press a key. I need the keypress to work like Ctrl+C does in most python scripts - it interrupts the script and kills it. In fact, a way to just capture a KeyboardInterrupt exception and handle it like normal would work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Curses allows input to be blocking, non-blocking, or "half-blocking" (where there's a wait, but only of limited duration). Nothing fancy needed, just call `nodelay()`. In this mode, `getch()` will return `ERR` if no input is waiting. (You should probably also call `cbreak()` before `nodelay()`, just to be on the safe side.)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `screen.getch()` in another thread, and make it raise `KeyboardInterrupt` in the main thread. Here is how to raise exceptions in other threads in CPython: https://gist.github.com/liuw/2407154

I don't know how stable this is in corner cases, but it's worth a try.

Alternatively, you can also install a `sys.settrace` to the main thread which would raise the exception when the other thread has finished reading a character, but `sys.settrace` makes your main thread much slower.